# Neovim CoC Popup overflow with dashes

Tags: elixir, neovim

I have a really annoying problem with NeoVim, and I was hoping someone here would know the problem to that.

I'm using NeoVim (0.5.1) with CoC and coc-elixir (on OSX in iTerm2). The problem is that the popup with autocomplete suggestions starts pushing dashes outside the popup window, and they stay there when I close the window. Like this:

Here you can see the dashes that overflow the window.
[image]

And here you can see that the overflown dashes stay there.
[image]

I've tried disabling all my normal settings, but it still happens. The only settings I still have are these:

```
" auto-install vim-plug
if empty(glob('~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
    \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  "autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall
  "autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall | source $MYVIMRC
endif

" Plugs
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/autoload/plugged')
  Plug 'elixir-editors/vim-elixir'
  Plug 'justinmk/vim-dirvish'
  Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
  Plug 'elixir-lsp/coc-elixir', {'do': 'yarn install && yarn prepack'}
call plug#end()

" CoC configuration
inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Tab>"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, for all future people, the problem was in iTerm2. I had to disable the setting 'Preferences -> Profiles -> Text -> Ambiguous characters are double-width'.